# NameError: name 'text' is not defined when importing new function named 'text'

Tags: python, string, text

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\ch6\analyze.py", line 46, in <module>
    words = text.split()
NameError: name 'text' is not defined
```

I have gone over my code to make sure I input it just as the book I am following states. I am working my way through Head First Learn to Code. Everything appears to be as it should be. I am at a loss why my code keeps throwing this error.

```
import ch1text

def count_syllables(words):
    count = 0

    for word in words:
        word_count = count_syllables_in_word(word)
        count = count + word_count

    return count

def count_syllables_in_word(word):
    count = 0

    if len(word) <= 3:
        return 1

    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    prev_char_was_vowel = False

    for char in word:
        if char in vowels:
            if not prev_char_was_vowel:
                count = count + 1
            prev_char_was_vowel = True
        else:
            prev_char_was_vowel = False

    return count

def count_sentences(text):
    count = 0

    for char in text:
        if char == '.' or char == ';' or char == '?' or char == '!':
            count = count + 1

        return count

def compute_readability(text):
    total_words = 0
    total_sentences = 0
    total_syllables = 0
    score = 0

words = text.split()
total_words = len(words)
total_sentences = count_sentences(text)
total_syllables = count_syllables(words)

print(total_words, 'words')
print(total_sentences, 'sentences')
print(total_syllables, 'syllables')

compute_readability(ch1text.text)
```

There is also a text file that was first a ch1text.txt file and I was told to open it in Python then save it as ch1text.py before importing it in Python. When I run the ch1text.py file it does run the text. What I am expecting is the other code to read through the text I imported and tell me how many words, sentences, and syllables are in the ch1text.py. Instead I get the error saying text isn't defined. Please help me. I have spent way too long trying to figure it out on my own and don't feel like I can move forward until I understand where I am going wrong.

*Edited with proper indentation to reflect what I have in my py document.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Indentation in Python is a _syntactic_ feature. Your posted code has numerous syntax errors, some of which may be responsible for the error that you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, indentation is used to [determine the grouping of statements](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html).

You probably just need to indent all lines that appear under:

```
def compute_readability(text):
```

Comment: They are indented in my python document but when I posted here the forum made me indent all of the main lines 4 spaces so the indentation is off. My code looks exactly how the book shows which is why I am so confused.

Comment: We don't have access to the book. Please edit your post and indent the code so it is exactly as it appears in your program. Sorry for being pedantic, but Python relies on spacing to interpret code.

Comment: Thanks Serge, I edited my document to show what I have in my Python document.

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies in function call. In your code where you are writing,

```
words = text.split() <--
total_words = len(words)
total_sentences = count_sentences(text) <--
```

if you carefully obeserve, text is not a global variable that is being passed to text.split or to count_sentences. So you need to fix that up. You can only split something that exists which in this case doesn't.

Comment: The other document that is called ch1text that was put into Python according to the book became a function that should be imported with this code.

Comment: The file that is supposed to be the stored function says                                                    text = """The first thing that stands between you and writing your first, real, 
piece of code, is learning the skill of breaking problems down into 
acheivable little actions that a computer can do for you. Of course, 
you and the computer will also need to be speaking a common language, 
but we'll get to that topic in just a bit."""

Comment: I think when it says text in my original code I shared it is referring to this file and function? If not, what could I do to fix it so that the ch1text can be imported as a function to work with the original code I posted?

Comment: @ChristinaVarghese so Christina your question was not really clear, but I thought I should do some research and look what I found: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=kytHDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA280&lpg=PA280&dq=import+ch1text+def+count_syllables(words):+count+%3D+0+for+word+in+words:#v=onepage&q=import%20ch1text%20def%20count_syllables(words)%3A%20count%20%3D%200%20for%20word%20in%20words%3A&f=false.

Comment: @ChristinaVarghese so the thing is if you observe carefully you will notice indentation is still incorrect... the line I was talking about in the answer needs to be indented inside the compute_readability(text) method. Please refer to the link I have mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you! I went back through and carefully paid attention to where my indentation was. I did see what you mean and fixed it. It is working now! Thanks for having patience with me and teaching me!

Comment: @ChristinaVarghese No worries... Glad I could help :)  Also if you found it helpful request you to mark my answer as correct with green tick on the left of answer.. :)